# Refresh dropdown after inserting registry in database PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, refresh, html-select

I have a dropdown list created with PHP using the CodeIgniter framework. The dropdown code is the following:

```
<?php
    echo form_dropdown('empresas', $idEmpresa, 'nombre');
 ?>
 <a onclick=newPopup("http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Test_controller/",300,1250) class="btn btn-primary" >Agregar nueva empresa</a>
```

With this code, I'm showing the current information of a database table in the dropdown. Then I have a button which invoke another controller that allows me to manipulate data of that particular table (this opens on a new popup window), so for example I do an insert on that controller and close the popup window, then I return to the page that have the dropdown, and the new registry that I inserted is not showed in the dropdown.

Is there some way to refresh the values of the dropdown? I investigated and read that this can be achieved using Javascript, but I'm not sure how to do it.

What I want to do is similar to the databind function that is on asp.net.

Comment: Can you add JavaScript to the close button(s) on the popup?

Comment: That's what I did, and in the Javascript function put the line window.opener.location.reload(false) provided by JOE LEE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child window after change:

```
window.opener.location.reload(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made the trick. Just to made it even more clear, I did it with Jquery and handled the ID of a <a> tag, then I put the line of code that you provide me. Thanks for taking the time to answer.